# AWS EC2 Image Builder: Action failed for step LaunchBuildInstance. Retry attempt: X

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-imagebuilder

Working with AWS EC2 Image Builder
Created the role as per the documentation.
Built a custom Ubuntu AMI,  everything worked fine.

Building a custom Windows AMI and it's stuck on LaunchBuildInstance step. Log shows:

> Action failed for step LaunchBuildInstance. Retry attempt: X

Waiting 90 seconds, retrying and failing.
No additional information in the logs

EC2 Build instance is running and I can connect to the Build Instance through the console, run PowerShell with no problem.
I see the AWS SSM agent is running.

Pipeline created with:

- Default image workflow
- Infrastructure configuration - Create using service defaults

Using a basic custom recipe that doesn't have much, just download a PS script from S3 and run it, taken from AWS documentation samples. It's not even getting to this point.